# fedora 25 webmin install

Tags: fedora, webmin

setting up my first server and ran into a problem while installing webmin.

I am following this tutorial to help me out (see 8:51): [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=571&v=iofsUZIf2nQ)

I do the following:

```
wget http://wwww.webmin.com/download/rpm/webmin-current.rpm

rpm -U webmin-current.rpm
```

on the second line i get

```
error: failed dependencies: 
      perl(Encode::Detect) is needed by webmin-1.840-1.noarch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `yum` or `dnf` to resolve dependencies instead of using `rpm` directly. If you do the following it will automatically install the perl RPM you need:

`sudo dnf install webmin-current.rpm`

Or if you really want to install via rpm directly, this will install the rpm you need:

`sudo dnf install 'perl(Encode::Detect)'`